# Swift JSON breaks when [ ] are used

Tags: ios, json, swift

In a simple project I'm working on, I am attempting to get JSON data from a url and print it out. However it seems Swift doesnt like JSON wrapped in [] even though its valid JSON.

Here is my Swift code thats getting/parsing the JSON.

```
func startConnection(){
    let urlName: String = "http://SOMEURL.net/jsonout.php"
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlName)!
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!
    connection.start()
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){
    self.data.appendData(data)
}
func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
    var err: NSError
    // throwing an error on the line below (can't figure out where the error message is)
    var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
    println(jsonResult)
}
```

Here is a sample of JSON that works

```
{   
  "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
  "Host": "headers.jsontest.com",
  "Referer": "http://www.jsontest.com/",
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0",
  "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
}
```

And a sample that causes the app to crash.

```
[
  {
      "artist": "Led Zeppelin",
      "requestname": "test",
      "title": "Stairway To Heaven"
  },
  {
      "artist": "Modest Mouse",
      "requestname": "test",
      "title": "Lampshades On Fire"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an array in second case, but still you are casting it to `NSDictionary`

Change the following code:

```
var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
```

to

```
var jsonResult: NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSArray
```